# How to add CSP nonce in inline style and script injected by Vue in a laravel and vue project using Vite

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, content-security-policy

I have a Laravel and Vue project in the same repo using Vite. I've implemented CSP using [spatie/laravel-csp](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-csp), everything works fine and in the header nonce for `script-src` and `style-src` is successfully generated when I inspect in the browser.

However, I'm getting the below errors.

`the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-nMxMqdZhkHxz5vAuW/PAoLvECzzsmeAxD/BNwG15HuA='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.`

`Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-H1R2LrVAcuLDIUMAB8wqwBzBFstVEppy'".`

I guess it's because the style and script don't have the nonce. How can I fix this?
Below is my custom policy and if you require more info or code please let me know.

```
<?php

namespace App\Support\Csp\Policies;

use Spatie\Csp\Directive;
use Spatie\Csp\Policies\Basic;

class CustomPolicy extends Basic
{
  public function configure()
  {
    parent::configure();



    $this->addDirective(Directive::FONT, ['fonts.gstatic.com'])
      ->addDirective(Directive::STYLE, ['https://fonts.googleapis.com'])
      ->addDirective(Directive::IMG, ['data:']);
  }
}
```

Comment: hello `->addDirective(Directive::SCRIPT, Keyword::SELF)` from  and `app(AppPolicy::class)->addDirective(Directive::SCRIPT, Keyword::UNSAFE_INLINE);
app(AppPolicy::class)->addDirective(Directive::STYLE, Keyword::UNSAFE_INLINE);` from [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-csp#usage)

Comment: @francisco, doesn't 'unsafe-inline' pose a security risk, as it allows the execution of inline scripts and styles? This would not work for me as well since I already have an inline script not generated by `Vue` that uses `nonce` therefore throwing the following error if I try it `Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.`

Comment: sorry.. on the policy file do `->addNonceForDirective(Directive::SCRIPT)         ->addNonceForDirective(Directive::STYLE);` by [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-csp#creating-policies) if you want nonce

Comment: That's already there by default from the `Basic.php` that I'm extending.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your `vite.config.ts`:

```
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  // something else

  // this might be needed in Dev mode
  const viteClientRegex = /node_modules\/vite\/dist\/client\/client\.mjs$/gi;

    // regex'es to add CSP
  // TODO: make one normal regex to handle all three
  const regexScript = /<script(.*?)/gi;
  const replacementScript = `<script nonce="${nonce}"$1`;

  const regexStyle = /<style(.*?)/gi;
  const replacementStyle = `<style nonce="${nonce}"$1`;

  const regexLink = /<link(.*?)/gi;
  const replacementLink = `<link nonce="${nonce}"$1`;

  const nonce = mode === "development" ? "nonce" : "{SERVER-GENERATED-NONCE}";

  return {
    plugins: [
      {
        name: "transform-file",
         // this might be needed in Dev mode
        transform(src, id) {
          if (viteClientRegex.test(id)) {
            return {
              code: src.replace(
                "style.setAttribute('data-vite-dev-id', id);",
                `style.setAttribute('data-vite-dev-id', id); style.setAttribute('nonce', '${nonce.toString()}');`
              ),
            };
          }
        },
      },
      {
        name: "html-inject-nonce-into-script-tag",
        enforce: "post",
        transformIndexHtml(html) {
          return html
            .replace(regexScript, replacementScript)
            .replace(regexStyle, replacementStyle)
            .replace(regexLink, replacementLink);
        },
      },
    ],
  };
});
```

You will obviously need to patch .html files on your server to include the nonce, for example with sub_filter in nginx (https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html). An example of good enough data for nonce in nginx is $request_id variable, while in PHP you can use crypto libraries for this purpose. Also make sure that the nonce is included in script-src and style-src sections of the CSP header.

Sometimes, you might have extra problems, when allowed scripts genuinely need to inject more scripts or styles into the page (let's call these scripts "special"). If you also encounter this issue, you could somehow safely store nonce in a safe place for your client and serve these special scripts, with necessary modifications made on-the-spot with your server software (nginx can do it, for instance). For example, you can store nonce in HTTP-only cookie, then serve our special script-injecting scripts with .css.js extension, so your server knows that they will also need to be patched on-the-spot. If you are using nginx to serve these scripts, you might also need to define `sub_filter_types`. Just make sure to change nonce for every new html loaded by client.